# jQuery .data() is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having problems with `.data`, this is the second time. If I use the `.data` here it does not add any data attribute:

`delete_button.data('to-do', toDoCount);`

Same as last time, it works doing

`delete_button.attr('data-to-do', toDoCount);`

I followed https://api.jquery.com/data/, specifically `$( "body" ).data( "foo", 52 );`

```js
// Create an initial toDoCount variable
    var toDoCount = 0;

    //  On Click event associated with the add-to-do function
    $("#add-to-do").on("click", function(event) {
      // prevent form from submitting
      event.preventDefault();

      // Get the to-do "value" from the textbox and store it a variable
      var thing_todo = $('#to-do').val().trim();

      // Create a new variable that will hold a "<p>" tag.
      // Then give it an ID in the following form:
      // "item-4" or "item-3" or "item-99", where the number is equal to toDoCount.
      // Then append the to-do "value" as text to this <p> element.
      var new_todo_element = $("<p>");
      new_todo_element.attr('id', 'item-' + toDoCount);
      new_todo_element.append(' ' + thing_todo);


      // Create a button with unique identifiers based on what number it is in the list. Again use jQuery to do this.
      // Give your button a data attribute called data-to-do and a class called "checkbox".
      // Lastly append the letter X inside.
      var delete_button = $("<button>");
      delete_button.data('to-do', toDoCount);
    //   delete_button.attr('data-to-do', toDoCount);
      delete_button.addClass('checkbox');
      delete_button.append('X');


      // Append the button to the to do item
      new_todo_element.prepend(delete_button);


      // Add the button and toDoItem to the to-dos div
      $('#to-dos').append(new_todo_element);

      // Clear the textbox when done
      $('#to-do').val('');


      // Add to the toDoCount
      toDoCount += 1;

    });

    //  When a user clicks a check box then delete the specific content
    //  (NOTE: Pay attention to the unusual syntax here for the click event.
    //  Because we are creating click events on "dynamic" content, we can't just use the usual "on" "click" syntax.)
    $(document.body).on("click", ".checkbox", function() {

      // Get the number of the button from its data attribute and hold in a variable called  toDoNumber.
    //   var item_id =

      // Select and Empty the specific <p> element that previously held the to do item number.


    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>To Do App!</title>

  <style>
    #todo-item {
      font-weight: 700;
      font-size: 2em;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Title -->
  <h1>My To Do's!</h1>

  <!-- Input Form -->
  <form>
    <span id="todo-item">To Do Item: <input id="to-do" type="text" ><input id="add-to-do" value="Add Item" type="submit"></span>
  </form>

  <hr>

  <!-- To-Do List -->
  <div id="to-dos"></div>
```

How can I set data attr on this button?

Comment: clearly, jQuery's `.data('to-do'` has nothing to do with html's `data-to-do` attribute ... `Same as last time, it works doing` - then do that ... or use DOM `element.dataset.toDo`

Comment: if you make answer that they're not the same i'll accept

Comment: I'm only 99.99% sure of it, I haven't researched it at all (trial and error in the past)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't worry, you're doing everything right. Setting stuff using the `data()` function doesn't change the underlying HTML, but still allows you to retrieve it later with `data()`. From the documentation:

> The data- attributes are pulled in the first time the data property is accessed and then are no longer accessed or mutated (all data values are then stored internally in jQuery).

The reason for this is of course optimization - why edit the HTML when you're going to retrieve it later through jQuery anyway? If you need to actually edit the document, `attr()` is your friend.

Comment: so that's why it's there, I just can't see it on inspect. thanks dmitry